# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, objectify

This is my Listener Class which registers my User Entity. The error occurs while registering my POJO class. However, my application works fine in local environment. After deploying to App Engine, I get Server error 500.

```
@WebListener
public class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

         public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce)  {}

         public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)  { 
                 ObjectifyService.register(User.class);
          }
    }
```

Below is my complete stack trace

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService
at com.appengine.listener.MyContextListener.contextInitialized (MyContextListener.java:23)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized (ContextHandler.java:843)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized (ServletContextHandler.java:533)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext (ContextHandler.java:816)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext (ServletContextHandler.java:345)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp (WebAppContext.java:1406)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext (WebAppContext.java:1368)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart (ContextHandler.java:778)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart (ServletContextHandler.java:262)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart (WebAppContext.java:522)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler (AppVersionHandlerMap.java:244)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler (AppVersionHandlerMap.java:182)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest (JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:97)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest (JavaRuntime.java:680)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest (JavaRuntime.java:642)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run (JavaRuntime.java:612)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run (JavaRuntime.java:806)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run (ThreadGroupPool.java:274)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)
```

The JAR files added in my application
[image: My JARS]

Comment: Please check in your build path, might be you have added two different jar's having class with same name.

Comment: How to check if two different jars have class with same name?

Comment: Are you using maven ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to manage dependencies yourself instead of relying on dependency information in the pom. It's hard to debug classpath issues over stackoverflow.

I suggest using maven and the appengine maven plugin. Get a project working using the Google's getting started guide and then add Objectify.

Answer (score 0):

May be this piece of code help you

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code where you are initializing the object of this class

This code first tries to load the above class before going ahead.

Comment: Now I get the following error in the line Class.forName() java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
   com/google/appengine/api/datastore/AsyncDatastoreService

Comment: Your application is unable to load these classes by self so you have to load all classes manually  by using the above snip.